# Save Rails ActiveRecord objects into a temporary table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, temp-tables

A user can import data into our website from a file.
The data normally contains several hundred Items (Item < ActiveRecord::Base).

Although the validations help, they cannot solve the problem of sanity-checking the content.
For that we would like to have a test mode.

Could we use a temporary Items table for this with Rails/MySQL, and, if yes, how should we do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AR Extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions/tree/master/ar-extensions/) gem for this. Read this [article](http://www.continuousthinking.com/2007/2/12/activerecord-extensions-0-4-0-released) for more details.

```
User.create_temporary_table do | temp_model|
  # now perform the inserts on temp table.
  temp_model.create(...)
  ...
end # table dropped automatically
```

**OR**

```
temp_model = User.create_temporary_table
temp_model.create(...)
#do something
...
...
#drop the temp table
temp_model.drop
```